# Mismatch between processor architectures

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Sou completamente novo no mundo de desenvolvimento de aplicações mobile. Ao tentar correr uma aplicação de teste obtenho este erro duas vezes:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "x86". 
>   This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. TestMobile.Core
>    mismatch  MSIL x86

Estou a utilizar VS2015, tenho a .NET 4.5 instalada, windows 8 SDK tools e o MultilingualAppToolKit.

Ja verifiquei no configuration manager e parece estar tudo ok, platform target "Any CPU".

Comment: Em algum lugar deve estar com plataforma específica. Mas não vai fazer diferença para o que você quer. Não consegue usar o .Net para desenvolver para Android. Pode usar o Mono, que é semelhante, mas não é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Exatamente, com o Xamarin é possível, mas o MSIL deve ser usado sempre como Any CPU e no projeto do Xamarin especificar o processador da plataforma, caso seja necessário. A própria ferramenta faz as alterações necessárias para a execução no processador/plataforma específica.

Comment: Para desenvolver .Net com C#  é necessário Xamarin. Talvez o companheiro não tenha instalado Xamarin para VS, o mesmo pode ser instalado a partir da instalação do VS2015.